# How to superimpose more than one image figure in a single figure using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, edge-detection, imshow

Based on this idea (fig) [image] 
I am trying to plot all these three outputs (edges) in one single image with different colors to represent each, (not something like subplot, or imshowpair). Still now my outputs are just three different images.[image]   [image]    [image]

```
clear all
close all
clc
%% ground truth
img = imread('22o.jpg');
img_gray = rgb2gray(img);
img_ground_truth = imread('22g.jpg');
img_ground_truth = im2bw(img_ground_truth);
cc = img_ground_truth;
%cc = img_ground_truth(11:54, 112:171);

%% Detected part
img_edge = edge(img_gray, 'canny');
dd = img_edge;
%dd = img_edge(11:54, 112:171);

%% True pixel, false pixel, true negative 
[m n] = size(cc);
true_pixel = zeros(m,n);
false_pixel = zeros(m,n);
false_negative = zeros(m,n);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        if (dd(i,j) == cc(i,j))
            true_pixel(i,j) = dd(i,j);          

        elseif (dd(i,j)~= cc(i,j))
            false_pixel(i,j) = dd(i,j);
        end
    end
end
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        if (cc(i,j)==1 && dd(i,j)==0)
            false_negative(i,j) = cc(i,j);
        end
    end
end
% subplot(2,3,1); imshow(cc); title('Gt');
% subplot(2,3,2); imshow(dd); title('Dc');
figure(1),imshow(true_pixel, 'ColorMap',[1 1 1;0 1 0]); 
title('True Pixel (TP)');
hold on
figure(2),imshow(false_pixel, 'ColorMap',[1 1 1;1 0 0]); 
title('False Pixel (FP)');
hold on
figure(3),imshow(false_negative, 'ColorMap',[1 1 1;0 0 1]); 
title('False Negative (FN)');
hold off
```

Comment: “not something like subplot” — but `subplot` is exactly what you want to use here. Have you tried that?

Comment: No, I want these all three edges will be imposed on one image, that we can see all these three colored edges in one. Although there will be some overlap, but it's okay.

Comment: In the figure you show 3 subplots. If you want to recreate that, you need `subplot`.

Comment: U mean like, subplot(1,3,1),imshow(e.g)?

Comment: If you have "false negative", there's a very good chance the other labels are "true positive" and "false positive", not "true pixel"

Comment: The literature proposed that terminology actually

Comment: Are you asking how to merge the 3 images into one, like `merged_image = cat(3, false_pixel, true_pixel, false_negative)`?

Comment: @beaker, that is the thing I was looking for. But just one little problem `merged_image = cat(3, false_pixel, true_pixel, false_negative);
%img_complement = imcomplement(merged_image)
%figure,imshow(img_complement);
figure,imshow(merged_image);
title('Final Output');`                                                                                                  if I use my color order`false_pixel, true_pixel, false_negative` that is following the color order perfectly, but black background does not looking good, so when I am using `imcomplement` that is giving CMY color order.

Comment: how to generate the RGB color order against white background as my above figures? thanks a lot. @beaker

Comment: @BipulMohanto I'll post an answer, but I there are problems with using white as the background in this case because if all 3 images overlap, it will show up as white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original solution I suggested in the comments was:

```
merged_image = cat(3, false_pixel, true_pixel, false_negative);
imshow(merged_image)
```

This results in an image in which the True Negative pixels are black:

[image]

(Please forgive the legend at the top, I used your images and was too lazy to remove it.)

If there is any possibility of overlap between the three images, this is the approach I'd use. If you want TN to be white, instead of adding the pixels to the desired channel, you can subtract them from the other two channels:

```
% turn images into logical arrays to use in indexing
true_pixel = logical(true_pixel);
false_pixel = logical(false_pixel);
false_negative = logical(false_negative);

% create RGB channels for all-white image
r_channel = ones(size(true_pixel));
g_channel = ones(size(true_pixel));
b_channel = ones(size(true_pixel));

% leave pixels in true_pixel image green
r_channel(true_pixel) = 0;
b_channel(true_pixel) = 0;

% leave pixels in false_pixel image red 
g_channel(false_pixel) = 0;
b_channel(false_pixel) = 0;

% leave pixels in false_negative image blue
r_channel(false_negative) = 0;
g_channel(false_negative) = 0;

% merge into RGB image 
merged_image = cat(3, r_channel, g_channel, b_channel);
imshow(merged_image)
```

Result:

[image]

Another possibility is to use indexed images as you did originally. The cleanest way to do that is to generate the different indices `{1,2,3}` in a merged image within your loop, so something like this in your last loop (and similar code in the other two):

```
...
false_negative(i,j) = cc(i,j);
merged_image(i,j) = cc(i,j)*3; 
...
```

Then at the end, combine all 3 colors into one colormap:

```
imshow(uint8(merged_image), 'ColorMap', [1 1 1; 0 1 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 1])
```